# Windows not showing up in boot menu, Debian

Tags: debian, windows, grub2

I primarily run MX Linux and occasionally need to boot into Windows. Today, I tried but windows was missing from grub.

I installed `os-prober` and confirmed that `etc/default/grub` showed `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`. I ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted, but still no Windows in grub.

Back in MX Linux, if I run `os-prober` the output is `/dev/sda4:MX 21.1 Wildflower (21.1 ):MX:linux` with Windows not found, but windows is installed on this same SSD.

I'm pretty confused as to how to proceed. Any input?

EDIT: I have run `bootinfoscript`. So the results are clear, I have MX Linux installed twice, each onto different SSDs, and one instance of Windows 10

[bootinfoscript results](http://pastie.org/p/7hUBw9riJDUbjkv7g8vFPR)

Comment: UEFI or legacy BIOS? Also, have you disabled Windows Fast Startup? If not, NTFS metadata will indicate Windows is effectively hibernated, and the NTFS driver won't want to touch it. That might interfere with `os-prober`'s detection process.

Comment: "UEFI or legacy BIOS" I have no idea. I was able to duel-boot Debian/Windows (primarily using Debian) for months, it is suddenly gone from grub. I recall disabling WFS and, as I said, I was previously able to repeatedly boot into it with no problem. I cannot now boot into windows to see if it's UEFI or legacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows allows UEFI boot only with a GPT-partitioned system disk, and legacy BIOS boot only with a MBR-partitioned disk.

Your `sda` is GPT-partitioned, but `sda4` has the legacy BIOS boot flag enabled. And the bootinfoscript you linked detects an `i386-pc` (i.e. legacy BIOS style) GRUB installed in the protective MBR of `sda`.

Both `sda` and `sdb` have an EFI System Partition (ESP for short), but a Windows UEFI boot manager (`\EFI\Microsoft\Windows\bootmgfw.efi`) is not detected on any of them.

Looks like your system was originally configured for GPT boot,  and then you installed a second copy of MX while (whether accidentally or out of ignorance) booting the installer in legacy BIOS mode, so it installed a legacy BIOS-style bootloader on a GPT-partitioned disk. And your BIOS apparently currently prefers legacy boot over UEFI. And in one of your MX installation attempts, you may accidentally have allowed the installer to format the ESP `sda1` that contained the Windows UEFI bootloader.

If your BIOS has a setting that allows you to change the current "legacy first, then UEFI" boot policy to "UEFI only", set it to "UEFI only" to avoid such a mess in the future. That might cause your system to boot to the MX installation on `sdb2` rather than the current MX with the root filesystem on `sda4`.

If you cannot change the boot policy of the BIOS, you must find out a way to figure out which boot targets displayed by the BIOS menus are UEFI and which are legacy, and only use the UEFI boot targets from this point onwards.

Since the Windows UEFI bootloader has apparently been destroyed, it and its configuration will need to be rebuilt. If you boot **in UEFI mode** from a Windows 10 installation media and use its "repair boot" functionality, it should do the right thing automatically. But you might want to temporarily disconnect or disable `sdb` while you do that, so Windows will be forced to pick the correct disk to rebuild the UEFI bootloader to. (The Windows 10 installer is known to sometimes have weird ideas on how to pick the disk where it will install the UEFI Windows bootloader.)

After that, you should be able to get into Windows - but not necessarily into either of your MX installations. The next step is to bring sanity to your (presumably most current) MX installation on `sda4`.

If MX Linux has a similar rescue mode as Debian has, boot from the MX installation media **in UEFI mode**, select the rescue mode in GRUB boot menu, select the locale and keyboard, then the rescue mode should kick in: it should automatically search for existing MX installations, and offer you to pick one of them to be mounted. Pick `sda4`. Once it's been automatically mounted, it will ask you whether to activate network interfaces or not. Say yes. Then it will give you a root shell and suggest a `chroot` command to use to access the mounted installation. Use the suggested command. Now, you'll be effectively in command-prompt-only mode in your `sda4` installation, and can start fixing it.

First, remove packages `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin` and install `efibootmgr`, `grub-efi-amd64`, `grub-efi-amd64-bin` and perhaps also `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and `shim-signed` (if you think you might enable Secure Boot) packages in their stead. Then run `grub-install /dev/sda`.

After this, your BIOS boot menus should now have items that will indicate the name of the OS to be booted: `Windows Boot Manager` for Windows, and probably something
referring to MX Linux. Make the "MX Linux" boot item as your primary boot target, and you should be all set.

You should also run `efibootmgr -v` as root to view the UEFI NVRAM boot variables, and learn to understand its output (it's not hard, but it's something that is completely new to UEFI and has no real legacy BIOS equivalent).

Sometimes flashing a BIOS may wipe these boot variables, which may cause your system to again boot into Windows only. But if you have an `efibootmgr -v` printout and a Linux boot media, you will be able to fix it very quickly.

Comment: In motherboard settings, "Boot Mode Select" is greyed out with "UEFI" chosen. All of the "boot options" below that begin with "UEFI..." (UEFI Hard Disk, UEFI  USB, UEFI CD/DVD, etc). By "figure out which boot targets are UEFI/legacy," is that what you mean? They all appear to be UEFI to me.

Comment: I only need the MX install on sdb, I am happy to delete the MX install on sda, but I haven't yet because I thought the boot partition was on sba. For instance, when I update the kernal on the MX install on sdb, I have to go to the sda MX install to run update-grub in order for the kernal to be bootable for the sdb installation.

Comment: I don't have access to any Windows Media that might help me to rescue this. I honestly only care about the MX install on sdb, that is my main workstation system.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I haven't recently installed anything on this system. These three OS installs have been on this PC for 8-9 months, working totally fine.

I have no data that I'm concerned with losing on MX sda nor on Windows. Ideally, I would be able to rescue Windows, but if I can't, thats fine.

Comment: Since apparently I need Windows media to rescue Windows on this system, can I just unplug sdb (the MX instance I absolutely can't lose) and then nuke sda? Would that clean up this mess? I have no idea how else to proceed.

Comment: Note that I used `sda` and `sdb` as they appear in the bootinfoscript output. It's possible that the disks might be detected in a different order when actually booting, so be careful. But `sdb1` seems to contain a UEFI GRUB bootloader that looks like it might be in working order, while `sda1` seems to be empty (or at least contain no `*.efi` files). Carefully nuking `sda` is possible, but technically overkill: with a Windows boot media, the existing Windows installation would be fairly easy to rescue. So far it seems just the Windows bootloader on `sda1` has been damaged.

Comment: My motherboard is a new MSI, "boot mode select" is greyed out and displays UEFI so I'm pretty sure my MB is not in legacy. I booted from a windows10 USB. When I select "startup repair" is says "Startup repair could not repair your PC." I did not unplug any ssds before trying this. Any idea what I might do from here?

Comment: Also, you made a point of writing "Boot from windows USB media in UEFI mode..." but I wasn't explicitly given an option to boot in any mode at all. I'm assuming my installation media has indeed booted me into UEFI mode since it seems my motherboard is in UEFI, but I'm not entirely sure how windows was booted from the USB media

Comment: The options offered by various BIOSes and their naming vary widely, and it's common to accidentally boot the installer in a wrong boot mode if the system cannot be explicitly set to "UEFI only" or "legacy only" modes. Regarding the startup repair, I'm out of ideas - perhaps ask in [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com), or just unplug `sdb` for safety, then nuke the `sda` as you planned.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.